# Jquery Popup gets hidden behind editlive editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application I have used EditLive Editor. When I try to open a popup on the same page where edtor is present it gets hidden behind it. Could anyone please help me how can i get my jquery dialog over the eitor.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try give a heigher z-index to jQuery dialog.

Code examples

```
//Initialize a dialog with the zIndex option specified.
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ zIndex: 3999 });
//Get or set the zIndex option, after init.
//getter
var zIndex = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "zIndex" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "zIndex", 3999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are dealing with is tied to how browsers and applets coexist.  In general the applet ignores z-index and always appears on top - this is not an EditLive issue but an issue with applets in general.

EditLive in specific has an API to address this called setBackgroundMode

- EditLive 8: http://docs.ephox.com/display/public/EditLive/setBackgroundMode+Method
- EditLive 6/7: http://docs.ephox.com/display/EditLive7/setBackgroundMode+Function

Note that you should wait for the callback to fire before performing other actions (e.g. displaying AJAX lightboxes)